# How to check if a void* is to a pointer on a valid instance of an object type?

Tags: c++, c, object, pointers, dll

I'm searching for the most common and robust way to check if a `void*` can be convert in a given C++ object type. You can see below some information about the context.

When I define a C API for a DLL, I often use void* to hide the C++ object I use behind (something like below)

```
typedef void* Instance_t;
int createInstance(Instance_t* pInst);
int processing(Instance_t inst, uint8_t* pBuf, size_t bufLength);
```

When I `createInstance` the code `cast` a pointer like that:

```
int createInstance(Instance_t* pInst)
{ 
   MyClass* ptr = new MyClass();
   *pInst = (void*)(ptr);
   //.... etc
   return 0;
 }
```

But the question is how can we later in all the other C function we define, check if the `void*` value we receive is a **valid** `MyClass*`. I think we can't as none of the C++ casting operator is really type safe is that case (even `dynamic_cast`).

for now my best solution is to use a C cast (or a `reinterpret_cast`) and if everything is ok with a call to a `IsValid` function define with MyClass.

Have you a better way to do that check ?

Comment: How would you know that the data is valid? What consistency test do you apply in your head? Apply that to the data received and if it passes the data might be fine.

Comment: forward declare your type and only define it in your `*.c` source. This avoids `void *` use since you want type-checking

Comment: If you're ok with RTTI, you can [perhaps do something like you wish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx)

Comment: @RogerRowland That only works with a pointer to a polymorphic type, not `void*`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes that's true, sorry, it would need a common base rather than `void*` and I hate the `CObject` type of approach.

Comment: In standard c++ there is no way to figure out what a pointer is pointing to. Even if it points to valid memory, unless the type is in some way polymorphic and you have the right type of base pointer, there is no information stored anywhere to figure out what that block of memory is.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that, unless you (say) allocate all your MyClass instances from a memory pool, and check the address you get passed is a pointer into to that memory pool. Or maintain a list of valid instances.

However, if you need to pass round an opaque pointer just make the client use

```
struct MyClass;
typedef struct MyClass *Instance_t;
```

This will compile cleanly and give you a reasonable amount of peace of mind. As long as you're only using the pointer, the compiler is happy. It's when it dereferences it, the compiler needs to know what the pointer actually points to.

Comment: I believe in proper `C` code this would be `typedef struct MyClass * Instance_t`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this, and I don't think you should be doing this. A `void *` is just a pointer to some location in memory. Almost by definition, there's no way to know what it points to.

But why are you typecasting everything to `void *`'s, why not use protected and private methods on your class if you want to prevent users from fiddling with the internals of your class?

Comment: Hum... how do you use `protected` and `private` in C already ?

Comment: Umm... we're talking about C++ here. You can't use `class` in C either, or any objects in C...

Comment: @craigmj he's talking about the C api though.

Comment: To clarify: the OP is asking how to structure his C API, so the solution presented need accommodate C in the public API provided, though may use C++ outside of it.

Comment: Ah, with you. So he returns a `void*` in the C API, then when receiving it back later, wants to be sure that it's a pointer to his/her own class. So then s/he doesn't have to worry about protecting class methods, since the C API is presumably the only access to the methods. But it doesn't get closer to being sure of the pointer... Leaves one with the first part of the answer, I guess ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to check that an untyped pointer points to a valid object of any particular type. If you use `void*`, you are throwing away type checking. Instead, you could declare the type in the C header, and use a pointer to that (incomplete) type rather than `void*`.

```
struct Instance;
int createInstance(struct Instance** pInst);
int processing(struct Instance* inst, uint8_t* pBuf, size_t bufLength);
```

Then in C++, you can define and use the class.

```
// Probably better to use "struct" rather than "class" in case
// some compilers complain about mixing class keys.
struct Instance {
    // Whatever
};

int createInstance(Instance** pInst) {
    *pInst = new Instance;
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Note: MSVC mangles `struct Instance` and `class Instance` differently and the C++ Standard recommends not to mix `struct`/`class` for the same type.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I've never heard of that recommendation. But if some compiler is broken in that respect, then perhaps it's better to stick to `struct` in both cases.

Comment: I would not say broken: **§7.1.6.3/3 [dcl.type.elab]** says *The class-key or enum keyword present in the elaborated-type-specifier shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the elaborated-type-specifier refers. [...] and either the class
or struct class-key shall be used to refer to a class (Clause 9) declared using the class or struct class-key.*; and it's not exactly cristal clear whether the `class` and `struct` are interchangeable.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: But that paragraph also specifies what "agree in kind" means: "**either** the `class` **or** `struct` class-key shall be used to refer to a class declared using the `class` or `struct` class-key". That seems clear enough to me. If it had to match exactly, it would say so, as it does with `union` and `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to determine if a `void*` points to a valid C++ class. Unless you've got RTTI enabled then there's no metadata associated with a class, and even then there are plenty of cases in C++ where a `void*` isn't pointing to a class. For example:

```
int x=10;
void *ptr = &x;
```

Here `ptr` is pointing to a raw value. There's no RTTI associated with the integer so how could you query it to determine anything>

Answer (score 0):

When I need to export some objects from my CPP lib to C code, I do:

```
typedef void * OBJ1;
typedef void * OBJ2;

OBJ1 createObj1();
OBJ2 createObj2();

void doObj1(OBJ1 obj);
```

So in do function I exactly knew what object to expect

Comment: That's more or less what the question describes. But, as the question says, there's no way to prevent errors like `do(createObj2());` if you're using (aliases of) `void*`. (Also, you can't call a function `do`, since that's a keyword).

Comment: You are quite right, "do" is reserved i was in a bit of hurry, i corrected my answer. So error of such kind as doObj1(createObj2()); is possibly because there is no way to strict check of typedef types. But at least it's the best way that i know to avoid confusion

Comment: I feel this `typedef void * OBJ1;` is confusing. And for the compiler it's no help at all.

Comment: @alk Compare this: doObj1( void * o ); doObj2( void * o ); and this doObj1( obj1_t  o); doObj2( obj2_t o). Also you can use "struct" keyword (typedef struct obj1 * obj1_t ) in typedef  and in such way doObj1( createObj1()) will fail on compilation.

Comment: The latter makes sense, the former pretends to be save but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: it can be difficult.

The issues are numerous, but basically boil down to the very low-level nature of operations accessible in C and C++ (note: accessible, but not necessarily legal). The very role of `void*` is that any pointer can be coerced to it, but should you be using another type anyway abuse of `reinterpret_cast` could still lead to troubles.

---

A simple solution is to use tagging. Essentially, put a type id in the pointer so that you can always know the original type of the object. It's onerous (as each and every type need be modified), but otherwise easy to deploy.

```
typedef enum {
    SP_ATag,
    SP_BTag,
    SP_CTag,
    ...
} SP_Tag_t;

// External Tag
typedef struct {
    SP_Tag_t tag;
    void* p;
} SP_Any_t;

// Internal Tag
struct A {
    SP_Tag_t tag;
    ...;
};

...

typedef union {
    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
} SP_Any_t;
```

Then, instead of using `void*`, you use `SP_Any_t`.

*Advantages*:

- lightweight
- external solution does not require modifying existing classes
- internal solution should be binary compatible with existing C code

*Disadvantages*:

- single place to declare all types
- corrupting the tag is easy (whether accidental or intentional)

---

A more involved solution, which can be a good debug help, is to introduce a *per type registry*. The downside is that you need to instrument existing types for it to work, still it's easy enough, and that it involves much more *runtime overhead*. But hey: [it works](http://ideone.com/WYsgYG)!

```
template <typename> class Registrable;

//
// class Registry
//
class Registry {
public:
template <typename> friend class Registrable;

template <typename T>
static T* Cast(void*);

private:
struct TagType {};

using Key = std::pair<TagType const*, void*>;
using Store = std::set<Key>;

template <typename T>
static void Register(Registrable<T>* t);

template <typename T>
static void Unregister(Registrable<T>* t);

static Store& Get();
}; // class Registry

template <typename T>
T* Registry::Cast(void* const pointer) {
TagType const* const tag = &Registrable<T>::Tag;

if (Get().count(std::make_pair(tag, pointer)) == 0) { return nullptr; }

return static_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<Registrable<T>*>(pointer));
}

template <typename T>
void Registry::Register(Registrable<T>* t) {
TagType const* const tag = &T::Tag;
void* const pointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>(t);

Get().insert(std::make_pair(tag, pointer));
}

template <typename T>
void Registry::Unregister(Registrable<T>* t) {
TagType const* const tag = &T::Tag;
void* const pointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>(t);

Get().erase(std::make_pair(tag, pointer));
}

Registry::Store& Registry::Get() { static Store S; return S; }

//
// class Registrable
//
template <typename T>
class Registrable {
public:
static Registry::TagType const Tag;

Registrable();
~Registrable();

Registrable(Registrable&&) = default;
Registrable& operator=(Registrable&&) = default;

Registrable(Registrable const&) = default;
Registrable& operator=(Registrable const&) = default;
}; // class Registrable

template <typename T> Registry::TagType const Registrable<T>::Tag;

template <typename T>
Registrable<T>::Registrable() { Registry::Register(this); }

template <typename T>
Registrable<T>::~Registrable() { try { Registry::Register(this); } catch(...) {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use pointers but handles

- if the memory is on the dll side do not pass pointers but handles to
  your objects only
- if the memory for your objects is allocated by the application and passed to the dll keep a table of those pointers and treat them as handles also

this works for a single dll. of course it does not work if pointers from 1.dll are passed to 2.dll via application. in this case you are on thinnest possible ice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with some limitations that uses RTTI...

if your instances all derive from a virtual base class, then you can reinterpret cast to that base class safely, and then dynamic cast to your other class...

```
class Object
{
   virtual ~Object() {}
};

class A : public Object
{
  static bool IsOfThisClass(void *data)
  { 
     return dynamic_cast<A*>((Object*)data) != 0;
  }
}
```

calling A::IsOfThisClass(someData)  will return true if  someData is of class A.

it's not the kind of hack you want to expose to a user, since it only works if void* points to a class derived from Object,   but it can be a useful building block in controlled situations.